# JavaFx WebView - how to scroll it to the bottom

Tags: javafx, webview

I have made a conversation stage in JavaFx with a WebView that is displaying whole conversation. I want to show it from the bottom where the newest messages are so I used a function "execute script":

```
    public void initialize() throws SQLException
{
    buildText();
    conversationText.getEngine().loadContent(text1);
    conversationText.getEngine().executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
    conversationText.getEngine().setUserStyleSheetLocation(getClass().getResource("/html/style.css").toExternalForm());
}
```

I wrote this function in an initialize() void but it doesn't work, when I open the conversation it shows me all from the top where the eldest messages are :

[image]

But what is interesting it works properly when I use this metod form a void that is connected with a button named "script"

```
public void script()
{
    conversationText.getEngine().executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
}
```

when I press this button it scrolls to the bottom :

[image]

Is there any way to do this correct in an initialize void ? I have tried many ways like inserting the button method script() into initialize but i noticed that if I use function webengine.loadcontent() it always displays me all from the top.
I want to show the user the newest messages at the bottom from the beginning , not after pushing a button.

Comment: Most likely, the page hasn't been fully loaded by the time you call `executeScript`. Try listening to the load `Worker`'s `state` property and execute the script when it has `SUCCEEDED`.

Comment: Thank You very very much it helped :) I added a listener and it works perfectly :)

Comment: Could you post your solution please?